# Points of intersection in middle of text

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to compare two arrayLists. Like so:

```
public class intersection {
 public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("This is a test example to help me learn hashsets"));
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("test example", "Not returned"));

    System.out.println(new intersection().intersection(list1, list2));

}


public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T t : list1) {
        if(list2.contains(t)) {
            list.add(t);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
}
```

I want "test example" to be returned as it is somewhere in both arrayLists. Sorry forgot to say that the content of the arrayLists can not be changed Is there anyway of doing this?. Thank you

Comment: You will have to do it on individual words if you are using a list. Else consider String.indexOf

Answer (score 2):

You either need check the individual words

```
public class intersection {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("This is a test example to help me learn hashsets".split("\\s+")));
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("test example Not returned".split("\\s+")));

        System.out.println(new intersection().check(list1, list2));

    }

    public <T> List<T> check(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (T t : list1) {
            if (list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can choose to search a whole string for phrases

public class intersection {

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    String s1 = "This is a test example to help me learn hashsets";
    String[] s2 = new String[] { "test example", "Not returned" };

    System.out.println(new intersection().check(s1, s2));

}

public List<String> check(String s1, String[] s2) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String s : s2) {
        if (s1.contains(s)) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

}

Comment: one suggestion @Leon , use "\\s+" instead of " ". So it will ignore more number of white spaces if exists between two words. i.e "<any string>".split("\\s+")

Comment: second solution will not check for individual words so I don't think that its correct solution.

Comment: Second solution is great as I am checking for the whole phrase from string 2 to be somewhere in string 1. I should have been clearer thanks. for the help all

Comment: @niks Yes, the second solution checks for phrases in a string. I do like your suggestion on the regex

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("This is a test example to help me learn hashsets"));
```

Here the list will only contain one element as "This is a test example to help me learn hashsets" is a single element.

Divide the string with **,**.

```
 public class intersection {
   public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("This is a ","test example"," to help me learn hashsets"));
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("test example", "Not returned"));

    System.out.println(new intersection().intersection(list1, list2));

  }


  public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T t : list1) {
        if(list2.contains(t)) {
            list.add(t);
        }
    }

    return list;
  }
}
```

Or change the logic of intersection to use substring.

**EDIT:**

```
public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T t : list2) {
        for(T l: list1){
            if(((String)l).contains((CharSequence)t)){
                list.add(t);
            }

        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that the arrayLists can't be edited, as in the bigger file they will be text files that can't be formatted. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use Java 8 streams:

```
public static <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Predicate<? super T> con = (t) -> {
        Predicate<? super T> p = (u) -> u.toString().contains((CharSequence) t);
        return list1.stream().anyMatch(p);
    };
    list2.stream().filter(con).forEach(list::add);

    return list;
}
```